# HTTPS vs VPN - which is more secure

Tags: tls, vpn

I understand that end-to-end VPNs (such as SurfShark and NordVPN) hide the domains I visit whereas HTTPS does not

However, are they any attacks that an HTTPS website would be subject to, that could be avoided if I used an end-to-end VPN?

The main kind of attack I am concerned about is having any secure information (such as passwords, bank details, mobile number etc...) I send to a website being intercepted by a "middle-man"

The question in essence is are there any security benefits from using a paid-for VPN such as Surfshark given I currently enforce HTTPS on my browser (meaning I block all HTTP websites) and all my banking websites use HTTPS.

- By security, I mean can any personal data be obtained
- Privacy is not as important an issue (e.g: can people see domains I visit)

Comment: Do you want to compare end-to-end VPN with end-to-end HTTPS? Or do you mean a common VPN where the connection between VPN exit and the real target site is no longer protected by VPN? And what kind of VPN you are talking about? And do you consider common issues when deploying VPN (i.e. IPv6 leaks or DNS leaks) a problem of  VPN in general or of the specific setup? And what do you want to be secure from anyway, i.e. what are the threats you care about? Too much question to provide a good answer. Please edit your question too provide more details.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question and hopefully it has a clearer focus.

Comment: _"I understand that end-to-end VPNs (such as SurfShark and NordVPN) hide the domains I visit whereas HTTPS does not"_ - they may hide it from your ISP, but not from the VPN provider itself or anyone between them and the destination website. But this is irrelevant  if your concern is _security_ rather than _privacy_.

Comment: Correct. I wanted to clarify that as privacy is not my concern. Does using a VPN add any security when HTTPS is enforced?

Comment: I have the feeling that you don't really understand what a VPN is and/or what end-to-end actually means. While you specifically ask for an end-to-end VPN you then mention products which are not end-to-end VPN as example (Surfshark). Also you ask about *"attacks that an HTTPS website would be subject to"* (i.e. attacks against one endpoint) while you seem otherwise concerned about attacks about protecting the communication to the server, which is something different. And in the title you want to compare VPN and HTTPS while later you ask if VPN in addition to HTTPS is useful.

Comment: Which is safer: a car or a tunnel?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: It's not EML's fault.  VPN advertisements are incredibly misleading.  EML, I suggest watching Tom Scott's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVDQEoe6ZWY) for a non-technical explanation of what VPNs offer, in the context of what VPN advertisements claim to offer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "... you then mention products which are not end-to-end VPN ..." So even you claim there is such a thing as "end-to-end VPN". There is no such thing, as far as I can tell. That combination of terms just doesn't make sense. Unless you mean "a VPN used to access resources on the *VPN provider's* internal network"?

Comment: "By security, I mean can any personal data be obtained" In this context, that's pretty much the definition of "privacy". So what's the difference between "security" and "privacy"?

Comment: @BrianDrake: *"So even you claim there is such a thing as "end-to-end VPN""* - VPN has a meaning outside of the "customer VPN" you seem to refer to. And with enterprise VPN and mobile users it is pretty common that the VPN starts in the user network and ends in the final target network where the internal applications are running, i.e. end-to-end in terms of network.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am well aware of such enterprise VPNs; in fact that is what my last sentence was referring to. But I was not aware there was a special name for them, and my quick search for "end-to-end VPN" didn't turn up anything. That's why I wasn't sure if you were trying to refer to them when you said "end-to-end VPN".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## What does TLS do?

From [wikipedia/HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS):

> The principal motivations for HTTPS are authentication of the accessed website, and protection of the privacy and integrity of the exchanged data while in transit. It protects against man-in-the-middle attacks, and the bidirectional encryption of communications between a client and server protects the communications against eavesdropping and tampering.

So the primary purpose of HTTPS is to protect your personal data.

## What does a VPN do?

From [wikipedia/VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network):

> A virtual private network (VPN) extends a private network across a public network and enables users to send and receive data across shared or public networks as if their computing devices were directly connected to the private network.
>
> ...
>
> VPN technology was developed to provide access to corporate applications and resources to remote or mobile users, and to branch offices.
>
> ...
>
> Internet users may secure their connections with a VPN to circumvent geo-blocking and censorship or to connect to proxy servers to protect personal identity and location to stay anonymous on the Internet.

So the primary purpose of a VPN is to connect to your company's network when you're out of the building. There is a secondary usage of VPNs to protect your anonymity (specifically your IP address) when accessing public websites.

---

Your questions:

> The main kind of attack I am concerned about is having any secure information (such as passwords, bank details, mobile number etc...) I send to a website being intercepted by a "middle-man". Privacy is not as important an issue (e.g: can people see domains I visit).

You want the thing that HTTPS is good at. You are not interested in the thing that VPNs are good at. Sounds like there's no reason for you to use a VPN :)

Comment: Another usage for a VPN is to access region-locked content, like BBC UK in another country, or a Youtube video you can't watch in some country or something similar. I believe it doesn't fall in the "protect your anonymity" part.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I would argue it still does fall in that category, because it's still about making sure your private data doesn't leak. In this case, the affected private information is the country you're in and you're trying to hide it from the website.

Comment: Another use of a non-end-to-end VPN such as NordVPN is to improve defences against local MITM attacks such as DNS poisoning, DNS typo squatting, misleading host certificates and rogue WifFi hotspots.

Comment: @TooTea You're right. According to the European Commission's Data Protection (https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/what-personal-data_en), the Public IP address is "personal data" (as refered in the document). A VPN will hide that, so, yes, it falls under the "protect your anonymity" part.

Comment: I'll note that https also protects against MITM attacks, including rogue wifi hotspots.  Of course, there are a ton of caveats.

Comment: Related to Ismael Miguel's point about region locked content, VPNs can also be used to circumvent blocks.  Knowledgeable travelers to China generally set up a VPN before going because the Great Firewall blocks an awful lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score 17):

This question is based on a wrong premise.

VPN’s do NOT protect you end-to-end.
A VPN is basically a second encryption layer to wrap your normal traffic in, it is encrypted until the VPN endpoint (or exit node).
This will “Protect the traffic from being readable” by any intermediate (your ISP mainly). They will see traffic is going from you to the VPN but nothing more.

HTTPS (HTTP with TLS) protects almost all data end-to-end. The data not encrypted are:

- Source IP
- Target IP
- the Hostname connecting to (through the SNI extension allowing for tls with virtual hosting, as an example the URL “HTTPS://site.example.com/page/1” would have the following in clear text in the header for SNI “host: site.example.com”)

In order to do a MiTM attack (Man in The Middle), you need a certificate that your browser will accept as valid. (E.a. Issued by an authorized Certificate Authority). This is the same with a VPN.

In short. A VPN only gives a limited form of privacy by having many people using the same (set) of IP addresses. (Hiding in the crowd).
HTTPS is about integrity, authenticity and identity (especially with client side certificates)
Or in other words HTTPS ensures the data is not tampered with, is from the original source. And is known from who it came.

Comment: "They will see traffic is going from you to the VPN but nothing more." – This kind of makes it sound like you're saying that nobody will see the traffic between the VPN endpoint and the website you're connecting to.

Comment: They as in the ISP will indeed not see anything but traffic between you and vpn provider. It is scoped as Bering an intermediate between you and the vpn provider.

Comment: However, the ISP of the VPN endpoint will see the traffic going from the VPN to the website. Basically, the MITM needs to be somewhere else. And if they're close to the website, they can intercept both connections.

Comment: You could also mitm the vpn ....

Comment: I think the statement *"VPN’s do NOT protect you end-to-end."* is a bit too strong. It can protect you end-to-end as long as **both** ends are connected to the VPN, **and** you control the VPN server. But yes, for the typical user that wants to connect to services he doesn't control, VPN cannot provide end-to-end protection.

Comment: @user000001 in that case it is still not the VPN protecting it end-to-end. End-to-end means nothing in between can read the data, the VPN can read the data, it’s not E2E protected.

Comment: The hostname you're connecting to is not encrypted, **except** when you use DoH + TLS 1.3 + ESNI.

Comment: TLS 1.3 support is not available for all servers yet. (It’s coming), downgrading tls 1.3 to 1.2 is usually still allowed disabling ECH (Encrypted Client Header). DoH does not magically make it the person running the services can not see what domain requested also it’s still in draft status (means thing can change). For the moment it’s safe to assume the hostname is not encrypted.(until DoH /DoT & TLS 1.3 & ECH are common)